# OutOfMemory exception when sending data in infinite loop

Tags: vb.net, exception, out-of-memory, infinite-loop

I'm trying to test a server by sending data in infinite loop, but after a while I have an `OutOfMemoryException` from my side.
I'm trying to identify from where this exception come.
Is the following code can cause this exception or I have to check somewhere else?

```
Dim myArray(49) As String
For count As Integer = 0 To myArray.Length - 1
   myArray(count) = "T"
Next    
Do
   Try
      Dim sMystruct As New Mystruct()
      sMystruct.mystring1 = "test"
      sMystruct.mystring2 = "test"
      sMystruct.value1 = 128
      sMystruct.value2 = 128
      sMystruct.misc = myArray

      myInstance.sendData(sMystruct)
      sMystruct = Nothing
   Catch e As Exception
       Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
       Console.Write(e.StackTrace)
   End Try
Loop Until False
```

Thanks

Comment: How long your `sendData` takes? It might be that loop is so fast that it makes so big memory pressure that GC is not able to free it.

Comment: Open the **Task Manager**, go to the **Processes** tab and show the **GDI Objects**, **User Objects**, and **Handles** columns.  See if any of those counts gets up to 10,000 when the exception is thrown.  Running out of handles is the most common cause of out-of-memory exceptions.

Comment: @Konrad Kokosa: It takes 6ms

Comment: @StevenDoggart: I opened the **Task Manager** during the running of my application and I saw the **Mem Usage** of the application increased to exceed 1,000,000K then I stopped it. I think that the exception comes from this. But I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that you posted which would cause that kind of problem.  My guess would be that the `sendData` method has a leak of some sort, but that's just a guess.  It's impossible to say with just this information.

Comment: I added a 'Sleep(10000)' after each 'sendData' and the **Meme Usage** didn't increase anymore. 
Thanks for your help I will analyze 'sendData' methode to.